# Django - Use Ajax to filter and display projects per category

Tags: django, ajax

I would like to use Ajax in my project in order to filter projects per category and display them in my template. I read a couple of articles but unfortunately i cannot figure out a way of how to implement it.
Any help is appreciated.

views.py

```
class WorkProjectsView(ListView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'work/work.html'
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'projects'
    ordering = ['-date_created']

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super(WorkProjectsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context

class CategoryDetailView(ListView):
    model = Category
    context_object_name = 'projects_categ'
    template_name = 'work/work.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.category = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return Project.objects.filter(category=self.category).order_by('-id')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CategoryDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

urls.py

```
path('project/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>', WorkProjectsDetailView.as_view(), name='project-detail'),
path('category/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>', CategoryDetailView.as_view(), name='category-list'),
```

work.html
In the below html i'm listing all projects. On the top of the page (work.html) i'm listing also all categories by using WorkProjectsView (see below). I would like when clicking a category to show all projects per category without reloading the page.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

    <main class="main-root">
        <div id="dsn-scrollbar">
            <header>
                <div class="container header-hero">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="contenet-hero">
                                <h5>Our Work</h5>
                                <h1>portfolio</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>

            <!--Project's list-->
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="root-work">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="box-title" data-dsn-title="cover">
                            <h2 class="title-cover" data-dsn-grid="move-section" data-dsn-move="-70">Projects</h2>
                        </div>

                        <div class="filterings">
                            <div class="filtering-wrap">
                                <div class="filtering">
                                    <div class="selector"></div>
                                  <button type="button" data-filter="All" class="active">All</button>
                                {% for category in categories %}
                                  <button type="button" data-filter="{{ project.category }}" class="filter-category">
                                    <a href="#">{{ category.title }}</a>
                                  </button>
                                  <!--<button type="button" data-filter="Web Development"></button>
                                  <button type="button" data-filter=".architecture">Architecture</button>
                                  <button type="button" data-filter=".video">video</button>-->
                                {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="projects-list gallery">
                          {% if projects %}
                            {% for project in projects %}
                            <div class="item brand">
                                <a href="{% url 'project-detail' pk=project.pk slug=project.slug %}" class="effect-ajax" data-dsn-ajax="work"
                                    data-dsn-grid="move-up">
                                    <img class="has-top-bottom" src="{{ project.featured_image.url }}" alt="" />
                                    <div class="item-border"></div>
                                    <div class="item-info">
                                        <h5 class="cat">{{ project.category }}</h5>
                                        <h4>{{ project.title }}</h4>
                                        <span><span>View Project</span></span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                          {% else %}
                              <div class="col-lg-8">
                                <p>No Projects Available</p>
                              </div>
                        {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--End of Projects List-->
```

script used:

```
<script>
  $('.filter-category').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var element = $(this); //button that was clicked
    $.ajax({
        url : 'category/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { filter_category : element.attr("data") },
});
</script>
```

html code generated

```
<div class="container">
                        <div class="box-title" data-dsn-title="cover">
                            <h2 class="title-cover dsn-move-section" data-dsn-move="-70" style="visibility: inherit; opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(0px, -45.486px, 0px);">Projects</h2>
                        </div>

                        <div class="filterings">
                            <div class="filtering-wrap">
                                <div class="filtering">
                                    <div class="selector"></div>
                                      <button type="button" data-filter="All" class="active">All</button>
                                    
                                      <button type="button" data-filter="" class="filter-category">
                                        <a href="#">Web Development</a>
                                      </button>
                                      <!--<button type="button" data-filter="Web Development"></button>
                                      <button type="button" data-filter=".architecture">Architecture</button>
                                      <button type="button" data-filter=".video">video</button>-->
                                    
                                      <button type="button" data-filter="" class="filter-category">
                                        <a href="#">Custom Software Development</a>
                                      </button>
                                      <!--<button type="button" data-filter="Web Development"></button>
                                      <button type="button" data-filter=".architecture">Architecture</button>
                                      <button type="button" data-filter=".video">video</button>-->
                                    
                                      <button type="button" data-filter="" class="filter-category">
                                        <a href="#">Branding</a>
                                      </button>
                                      <!--<button type="button" data-filter="Web Development"></button>
                                      <button type="button" data-filter=".architecture">Architecture</button>
                                      <button type="button" data-filter=".video">video</button>-->
                                    
                                      <button type="button" data-filter="" class="filter-category">
                                        <a href="#">E-Commerce Development</a>
                                      </button>
                                      <!--<button type="button" data-filter="Web Development"></button>
                                      <button type="button" data-filter=".architecture">Architecture</button>
                                      <button type="button" data-filter=".video">video</button>-->
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="projects-list gallery" style="position: relative; height: 2436.78px;">
                          
                            
                            <div class="item brand" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                                <a href="/project/6/physiosphere" class="effect-ajax" data-dsn-ajax="work" data-dsn-grid="moveUp">
                                    <img class="has-top-bottom" src="/media/photos/2021/01/05/Physiosphere_Front_Cart-min.jpg" alt="" style="transform: translate(0%, 0.934343%) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
                                    <div class="item-border"></div>
                                    <div class="item-info">
                                        <h5 class="cat">Branding</h5>
                                        <h4>Physiosphere</h4>
                                        <span><span>View Project</span></span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="item brand" style="position: absolute; left: 555px; top: 0px;">
                                <a href="/project/5/laurelnymph" class="effect-ajax" data-dsn-ajax="work" data-dsn-grid="moveUp">
                                    <img class="has-top-bottom" src="/media/photos/2021/01/05/Slider_Mockup_Laurelnymph.jpg" alt="" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
                                    <div class="item-border"></div>
                                    <div class="item-info">
                                        <h5 class="cat">Web Development</h5>
                                        <h4>Laurelnymph</h4>
                                        <span><span>View Project</span></span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="item brand" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 725px;">
                                <a href="/project/4/karakasis" class="effect-ajax" data-dsn-ajax="work" data-dsn-grid="moveUp">
                                    <img class="has-top-bottom" src="/media/photos/2021/01/05/Karakasis_Stamp-min.jpg" alt="">
                                    <div class="item-border"></div>
                                    <div class="item-info">
                                        <h5 class="cat">Branding</h5>
                                        <h4>Karakasis</h4>
                                        <span><span>View Project</span></span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="item brand" style="position: absolute; left: 555px; top: 885px;">
                                <a href="/project/3/evillio" class="effect-ajax" data-dsn-ajax="work" data-dsn-grid="moveUp">
                                    <img class="has-top-bottom" src="/media/photos/2021/01/04/Evillio_Pin_Button_Mockup-min.jpg" alt="">
                                    <div class="item-border"></div>
                                    <div class="item-info">
                                        <h5 class="cat">Branding</h5>
                                        <h4>Evillio</h4>
                                        <span><span>View Project</span></span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="item brand" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 1501px;">
                                <a href="/project/2/anclub" class="effect-ajax" data-dsn-ajax="work" data-dsn-grid="moveUp">
                                    <img class="has-top-bottom" src="/media/photos/2021/01/04/Slider_Mockup_Anclub_msOsUHA.jpg" alt="">
                                    <div class="item-border"></div>
                                    <div class="item-info">
                                        <h5 class="cat">Web Development</h5>
                                        <h4>AnClub</h4>
                                        <span><span>View Project</span></span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="item brand" style="position: absolute; left: 555px; top: 1661px;">
                                <a href="/project/1/spearguns" class="effect-ajax" data-dsn-ajax="work" data-dsn-grid="moveUp">
                                    <img class="has-top-bottom" src="/media/photos/2021/01/05/speaguns-home-slider.jpg" alt="">
                                    <div class="item-border"></div>
                                    <div class="item-info">
                                        <h5 class="cat">Web Development</h5>
                                        <h4>Spearguns</h4>
                                        <span><span>View Project</span></span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            
                          
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: What did you attempt to do, where did you fail

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Just to tell you i'm not quite familiar with ajax and jquery. I've updated the question with a script i used just for testing.

Comment: Hi, are you already displaying all `projects` in your work.html page ? If yes why not simply `hide()` and `show()` divs depending on category user selects instead of making ajax call .

Comment: @Swati. Thank you for comment. Yes, i'm showing all categories in work.html file. I was thinking of using Ajax for not reloading the page. Apparently this is a good idea. Could you please show me how can i do that in my case?

Comment: can you show  html of your `projects` divs and how you differentiate them ?

Comment: I've updated initial question with more info of how i'm  listing projects and categories. But now i'm thinking that `show()`, `hide()` will not work in my case.

Comment: here `{{ project.category }}` is category ? ie : `brand,video..etc` ?

Comment: Right. Get categories from db and show them in template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in your html structure `.cat` has category type you can use this to match with the `data-attr` of the button.So, whenever button is clicked get the `attr` value and using `.each` loop compare these value and `show()` div where value matches.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('.filter-category').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //get data attr
  var element = $(this).data('filter');
  console.log(element)
  if (element != "All") {
    //hide item divs
    $('.gallery .item').hide()
    //loop through item divs
    $('.gallery .item').each(function() {
      //if the .cat is equal to elemnts
      if ($(this).find('.cat').text() === element) {
        $(this).show() //show
      }
    })
  } else {
    $('.gallery .item').show()
  }
})
```

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filterings">
  <div class="filtering-wrap">
    <div class="filtering">
      <div class="selector"></div>
      <button type="button" data-filter="All" class="active filter-category">All</button>

      <button type="button" data-filter="Web Development" class="filter-category">
                                        <a href="#">Web Development</a>
                                      </button>


      <button type="button" data-filter="Custom Software Development" class="filter-category">
                                        <a href="#">Custom Software Development</a>
                                      </button>

      <button type="button" data-filter="Branding" class="filter-category">
                                        <a href="#">Branding</a>
                                      </button>

      <button type="button" data-filter="E-Commerce Development" class="filter-category">
                                        <a href="#">E-Commerce Development</a>
                                      </button>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="projects-list gallery" style="position: relative; height: 2436.78px;">


  <div class="item brand" style="">
    <a href="/project/6/physiosphere" class="effect-ajax" data-dsn-ajax="work" data-dsn-grid="moveUp">

      <div class="item-border"></div>
      <div class="item-info">
        <h5 class="cat">Branding</h5>
        <h4>Physiosphere</h4>
        <span><span>View Project</span></span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="item brand" style="">
    <a href="/project/5/laurelnymph" class="effect-ajax" data-dsn-ajax="work" data-dsn-grid="moveUp">

      <div class="item-border"></div>
      <div class="item-info">
        <h5 class="cat">Web Development</h5>
        <h4>Laurelnymph</h4>
        <span><span>View Project</span></span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="item brand" style="">
    <a href="/project/4/karakasis" class="effect-ajax" data-dsn-ajax="work" data-dsn-grid="moveUp">

      <div class="item-border"></div>
      <div class="item-info">
        <h5 class="cat">Branding</h5>
        <h4>Karakasis</h4>
        <span><span>View Project</span></span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="item brand" style="">
    <a href="/project/3/evillio" class="effect-ajax" data-dsn-ajax="work" data-dsn-grid="moveUp">

      <div class="item-border"></div>
      <div class="item-info">
        <h5 class="cat">Branding</h5>
        <h4>Evillio</h4>
        <span><span>View Project</span></span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="item brand" style="">
    <a href="/project/2/anclub" class="effect-ajax" data-dsn-ajax="work" data-dsn-grid="moveUp">

      <div class="item-border"></div>
      <div class="item-info">
        <h5 class="cat">Web Development</h5>
        <h4>AnClub</h4>
        <span><span>View Project</span></span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="item brand" style="">
    <a href="/project/1/spearguns" class="effect-ajax" data-dsn-ajax="work" data-dsn-grid="moveUp">

      <div class="item-border"></div>
      <div class="item-info">
        <h5 class="cat">Web Development</h5>
        <h4>Spearguns</h4>
        <span><span>View Project</span></span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help! But how i will get projects from db without django elements? If i understand correctly i should remove django code, right? Sorry but i'm new to all these.

Comment: No.. that htmls are just for demo .Your django code will render above htmls . I have just created dummy code you don't have to remove django code..only changes you need to make is in `jQuery` code and only make sure `data-filter` value and `<h5 class="cat">` value  should be same.

Comment: Hi , let me know if you face any issues :)

Comment: Hi Swati, sorry again, but i couldn't figure out how to implement it. If you could please help me to make it work. I copied your `JQuery` code to my template, and i added `data-filter="{{ project.category }}"` same as `<h5 class="cat">{{ project.category }}</h5>` but didn't work.

Comment: can you show html genrated of your code ? you can find that when you open your elements tab of browser console.

Comment: Thank you for comment :)! I added to the initial question, html code generated section

Comment: Hi, i have updated with your htmls ...have a look . Inside `data-filter` give your category name .

Comment: I added some extra Django code in the template and now it works!! Thank you for your help and assistance! :)